# Mysql Bitwise operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table so this table have one column which name is bit_column. And type of this column is varchar(64). this column only contain zeros and ones. (Ex: '1010100010011110111011101.....'). I want to XOR this column with given string (this string also contain zeros and ones). For ex: BIT_COUNT(b'01001' ^ b'01101') this return 1. So how can i do it on table column?

Comment: Storing binary data in a `VARCHAR` seems like a poor choice to me, and has given rise to the issue you are experiencing right now.  Can you change the design to store it more apporpriately (and therefore allow bitwise operations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the column value and the *given string* to decimal integer number with `CONV()` and `CAST()` and apply the bitwise `XOR` operator `^`.
Then convert the result to binary and left pad it with zeroes :

```
SET @s = '0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011';
SELECT
  LPAD(CONV(
    CAST(CONV(bit_column, 2, 10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) 
    ^ 
    CAST(CONV(@s, 2, 10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
    10, 2
  ), 64, '0')
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kEQkmhEZrikhtui2aWw3s/3).